# getting UI issue with iOS7 taped on bottom

Tags: iphone

I am an create iphone app that i am getting UI issue with iOS7 taped on bottom(between heigth 470px and 568px) in iphone 5. The app used to support both iOS 5, iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Comment: check your tap view of superview frame size.

Comment: You need to provide more information before anyone can help you. What exactly is the problem, and what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone 5 simulator - Cannot click on bottom of screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678864/iphone-5-simulator-cannot-click-on-bottom-of-screen) assuming you mean "tapped" rather than "taped" and your problem is that you can't tap on the bottom of the screen